# Expandable/Collapsible TableRow in Android

Tags: android-layout

I want to build an expandable/collapsible TableRow. I have two rows and I want an expandable or collapsible button (like a small 'v') on the second row. Upon clicking the button, I want to expand the 2nd row with some other views. I am very new to android development, and I am not sure how to achieve this. This is what I currently have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4B0082">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_layout"
        android:layout_width="370.0dp"
        android:layout_height="350.0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"      
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <TableRow           
            android:background="@drawable/top_table_row_appearance">
            <TextView
                android:text="HNL"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="LAS"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow           
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=""
            android:background="@drawable/tail_table_row_appearance">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"                                
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_child_friendly_black_24dp"/>
                <!--I want a collapsible button here. When I click it, this row should expand itself showing additional hidden views-->
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have a look at this component: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: @AleksG I found many such custom layouts. Is there any traditional android way to achieve this without creating a custom layout ? I thought this could be done much easier than this. Sorry, I am very new to android. Open to take any advise or discussions :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "traditional android way". There's an ExpandableListView component (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView) that you could use, but it's likely going to be less performant than something based on a RecyclerView and probably require more effort to implement.